# Pyspark connector invalid connection string

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, mongodb-atlas

i'm having problems connecting to a mongodb atlas serverless instance, i downloaded the spark connector from the [repo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark) and updated a jar to my Azure Synapse Spark Pool instance, trying to connect with this code snippet:

```
query = (  spark.read.format("mongodb")
        .option('spark.mongodb.connection.uri', 'mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@SERVERURL.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
        .option('spark.mongodb.database', 'test') \
        .option('spark.mongodb.collection', 'test4') \
        .load())
```

But it says

> Invalid connection string: 'mongodb+srv:/USER:PASSWORD@SERVERURL.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
> Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: A TXT record is only permitted to contain the keys [authsource, replicaset], but the TXT record for 'SERVERURL.mongodb.net' contains the keys [loadbalanced, authsource]

What does this mean? it seems the url is wrong but in other snippets i have seen on the forums it seems to be well specified.

My versions are:
spark: 3.2.2+
python: 3.8+
mongodb-driver-3.9.1.jar
mongo-spark-connector-10.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
mongodb-driver-core-3.9.1.jar
bson-3.9.1.jar

Comment: Did you get your connection string by clicking on the `Connect` button while logged in to Atlas?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yea. i think the problem is that my instance is serverless

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you remove `?retryWrites=true&w=majority` from the connection string?